# Can't install apache2 properly on RPi3

Tags: raspbian-jessie, apache-httpd

I try to run `apache2` on my RPi3 on Raspbian Jessie with this tutorial : https://www.stewright.me/2015/08/tutorial-install-apache-php-and-mysql-on-a-raspberry-pi-2/

Everything runs fine during the installation, but when I try to go on my local IP, I get a 404 error.

I have tried purging and reinstalling it but nothing changes.
What I can do to make it work?

EDIT: I have `domoticz` installed too, maybe this can be a issue?

Comment: Domoticz shouldn't be a problem

Comment: Try installing using these instructions https://www.raspberrypi.org/learning/lamp-web-server-with-wordpress/worksheet/. Just skip the wordpress part.

Answer (score 1):

A 404 error mean that apache is succesfully installed but the page you request is not found.

check apache error log ( cat /var/log/httpd/error_log ) to see where it is looking for the file. Maybe you request a .php page without installing php.

Answer (score 0):

"A 404 error mean that apache is succesfully installed but the page you request is not found" as zarvox said. It is correct. I believes your local IP is showing 404 due to Domoticz and apache2 server is running on same port(port 8080). [So change port of apache2 to some another port as mentioned in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41317582/change-port-of-apache-web-server) and restart your Apache server. To change the Apache server default port read this [article](http://www.noveldevices.co.uk/rp-webserverport).